# org-mode goto last heading?

Tags: org-mode

org-mode goto last heading in the current tree.

Say This is my org-file, pipe indicates the cursor:

```
* Top|
** Apple
** Banana
** Cherry
* Middle
** Ape
** Bear
** Cat
```

I'd like to run a command and have my cursor now be here:

```
* Top|
** Apple
** Banana
** Cherry|
* Middle
** Ape
** Bear
** Cat
```

Comment: Last heading in the file, or the current tree?

Comment: @Zavior Good question. I've clarified the original question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's actually an `org-end-of-subtree` function, but it's not interactive. You can simply define your own command:

```
(defun goto-last-heading ()
  (interactive)
  (org-end-of-subtree))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a command, based on @itsjeyd's answer, that is robust to the edge case listed in the comment to that answer (that is, when you're on the last heading/subtree):

```
(defun org-end-of-subtree ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-special-ctrl-a/e t))
    (if (condition-case nil
            (outline-forward-same-level 1)
          (error t))
        (progn
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (outline-back-to-heading))
      (outline-previous-visible-heading 1))
    (org-end-of-line 1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a built-in command for this, but you can easily define one yourself:

```el
(defun org-goto-last-heading-in-tree ()
  (interactive)
  (org-forward-heading-same-level 1)     ; 1. Move to next tree
  (outline-previous-visible-heading 1)   ; 2. Move to last heading in previous tree
  (let ((org-special-ctrl-a/e t))        ; 3. Ignore tags when
    (org-end-of-line)))                  ;    moving to the end of the line
```

And bind it to a key sequence of your choosing via:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c g") 'org-goto-last-heading)
```

Comment: this is nice, thanks for sharing, however maybe I need to be clearer in my question. What I really want is to go to the end of the current tree...

Comment: @AlexBaranosky Yes, that was not clear from the way you originally worded the question. Give me a sec to adjust the code...

Comment: @AlexBaranosky OK, that should do it. Thanks for clarifying your requirements!

Comment: I'd suggest not using `C-c l` binding. It is the org mode suggested binding for [`org-store-link`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html) as it is very closely related to `org-insert-link` (`C-c C-l`).

Comment: @kaushalmodi Yes, thank you. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: There's an edge-case problem to consider: if you're on the *last* header/subtree, it doesn't work as intended.  In OP's example, if he's on the `Middle` header, we'd like to get to `Cat`, but we actually end up on `Cherry`.  That's because the call to `org-forward-heading-same-level` doesn't move if there's no next heading.

Comment: @Dan Good catch :)